# Trie double free or corruption in destructor

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, destructor, prefix

I am writing a Prefix Tree class in C++. Each node in the tree has an array of length 27 of `Node*`. These are to hold letters and spaces. I sanitize any input to the tree by casting all letters to lowercase and all symbols to spaces. In the destructor I call a function called clear which accepts a node (root node first). When writing unit tests, It only makes it past one test successfully, and the second test that calls a destructor on the Prefix class fails with a double free or corruption error. I have ran across this before and have been able to detect the problem and remedy it, however I cannot figure out what is causing this, here is some code:

#### Node struct:

```
const unsigned int B_FACTOR = 27;  // a..z plus space

struct Node_t {
    bool word;
    Node_t *links[B_FACTOR];
    Node_t(): word(false) {}
};
```

#### Insert (public and private):

```
bool Prefix::insert(string thing) {
    sanitize(thing);
    if(!root) root = new Node_t();
    if(thing == "") return true;
    insertPrivate(thing, root);
    return true;
}

void Prefix::insertPrivate(string input, Node_t *node) {
    if(input == "") {
        node->word = true;
        return;
    }
    int idx = (int(input[0])-97) >= 0 ? (int(input[0])-97) : 26;
    if(!node->links[idx]) node->links[idx] = new Node_t();
    insertPrivate(input.substr(1, input.length()), node->links[idx]);
}
```

#### Destructor:

```
Prefix::~Prefix() {
    clear(root);
}
```

#### Clear:

```
void Prefix::clear(Node_t *node) {
    if(!node) return;
    cout << "On Node " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; ++i) {
        clear(node->links[i]);
    }
    delete node;
}
```

#### Unit Tests:

```
void testInsert0() {
    cout << "testInsert0" << endl;
    Prefix a;
    a.insert("a");
    TS_ASSERT(a.isStored("a"));
}

void testInsert1() {
    cout << "testInsert1" << endl;
    Prefix b;
    b.insert("dd");
    TS_ASSERT_EQUALS(b.isStored("d"), false);
}

void testInsert2() {
    cout << "testInsert2" << endl;
    Prefix a;
    a.insert("abcdef");
    TS_ASSERT(!a.isStored("abcd"));
}
```

Output to making the tests is this:

```
Running cxxtest tests (4 tests).testInsert0
On Node 
On Node 
.testInsert1
Post test
On Node 
On Node 
On Node 
On Node 
On Node 
*** Error in `./testrunner': double free or corruption (out): 0x00000000019652a0 ***
make: *** [test] Aborted (core dumped)
```

When I comment out the code in the destructor that calls the clear function, it all works (of course with plenty of memory errors) but when the destructor is active, it cannot make it past 2 full unit tests that exercise its ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a case where not all the variables are initialised, which is causing a spurious call to `delete`. Ensure that each link the `Node_t` struct is set to `nullptr` before it's used.

Also check out [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), which runs your program in a virtual machine to check for common memory issues - it's very useful for this sort of thing.

Comment: I'm confused, If I make a new Prefix pointer and don't delete it, how will that change what the destructor does?

Comment: Also I don't believe the root pointer is on the stack, because in `insert` I am checking to see if root exists, if it doesn't I allocate a new one with `new`

Comment: Are you setting the root element to `nullptr` in your constructor for `Prefix`?

Comment: Yes, well I am setting it to NULL because for this assignment the auto-grader doesn't include `-std=c++0x` for `nullptr` support but I am setting to `NULL`

Comment: It may also be that the `links` field in your `Node_t` struct might be uninitialized, are you setting each element to `NULL` when you create a new one of those?

Comment: Good call, I just did `Node_t *links[B_FACTOR] = {NULL}` and it worked perfectly thank you very much. I assume the values in the array had very crazy values, but were technically not `NULL` so clear didn't know when to stop and it would either seg-fault or double free. Thanks!